# iterating pandas rows using .apply()

Tags: pandas, loops, literate-programming

I wanted to iterate through the pandas data frame but for some reason it does not work with .apply() method.

```
train = pd.read_csv('../kaggletrain')

pclass = train['Pclass']

#  pclass has list of data with either 1, 2 or 3.. 
#  so wanted to return if the cell is 1 then return True or everything False

def abc(pclass):
    if pclass == 1:
        return True 
    else: 
        return False 
    

ABCDEFG = train.apply(abc, axis=1)
```

This gives valueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thank you for your help

Comment: `ABCDEFG = train['Pclass'].astype(bool)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang not sure what you meant ?

Comment: I' rewriting your `apply` function in an easier way: `ABCDEFG = train['Pclass'] == 1`.

Comment: Don't pass axis=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABCDEFG = train[train['pclass']==1]
```

Comment: Thank you @Mortz that will do for now